# How to get Imagemagick to use littlecms2 on WHM Centos 7

Tags: imagemagick, centos7, whm

I have Imagemagick running fine. However it is missing the lcms2 library that lets it utilise icc color profiles.So it was installed via RPM and also with  for different versions of PHP with the PECL php wrapper. I have installed lcms2 also from RPM.
However imagemagick doesn't know anything about lcms2. 
How can I add lcms2 delegate/library to my current imagemagick install?
Do I have to make my own build of imagemagick with flags to include lcms2? I hear lcms was removed from the Centos Imagemagick RPM due to security concerns.

Comment: Which RPM did you install? Package `ImageMagick-7.0.7-25.src` lists `lcms2-devel` as a dependency.

Comment: Thru WHM installer it says:Package ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-15.el7_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version. Have updated rpm db too.

Comment: Sorted now. wget the three rpms src, lib and dev tools. Then install pecl imagemagick wrapper and restart php-fpm. All good now with PDF to jpeg and correct colors. thx for the nudge